# Set local store to one virible - javascript

Tags: javascript

I am making a simple Tetris game in JavaScript.

I'd like to set that the player set a new score save on local storage.

I have tried some tips an examples and I don't understand how to do it.

My js code :

```js
function updateScore() {
    var hiscore = document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = "Score : " + player.score;

function saveData(x) {
    Tsocre = player.score;
    localStorage.setItem('highscore', Tsocre);
    savedHighscore = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('highscore'), Tsocre);
    if (Tsocre > savedHighscore) {
        Tsocre = savedHighscore;
    }
    alert("Highscore: " + Tsocre);
}   


function palyerReset() {
    const peices = 'ILJOTSZAW';
    player.matrix = createpeices(peices[peices.length * Math.random() | 0]);
    player.pos.y = 0;
    player.pos.x = (arena[0].length / 2 | 0) - (player.matrix[0].length / 2 | 0);

    if (collide(arena, player)) { 
        arena.forEach(row => row.fill(0));
        alert('Game Over!, try again.');
        player.score = 0;
        updateScore();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are setting the high score in localstorage, then retrieving this same high score and checking if it is the high score. What you should do is;

- Get the high score from localstorage
- Compare it with the player score
- If the player score is higher, set it as the high score in localstorage, and alert the user.

  ```
     function saveData(x) {
      Tsocre = player.score;

      savedHighscore = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('highscore'), Tsocre);
      if (Tsocre > savedHighscore) {
          localStorage.setItem('highscore', Tsocre);
          Tsocre = savedHighscore;
          alert("Highscore: " + Tsocre);
      }



  }
  ```